# How to make a select list from a list of comma-separated values in a table cell in Oracle Apex?

Tags: sql, list, select, oracle-apex

I have a table called **Products** and it has the following 3 columns: **ID**, **Name** and **Versions**. For any given row, the **Versions** column may have a number of versions separated by commas. What I'm wondering is how can I create a select list in my Apex application that would contain in it's LOV, each version that is separated by a comma?

Example, if I have the following row in the **Products** table:

```
1 | myProduct | 1.0, 1.1, 1.2
```

How can I create a select list in my Apex application that would display the following LOV: '1.0', '1.1' or '1.2'?

Comment: Maybe a good question too: why are these values in a comma-separated value? Why not in a table "versions"? Maybe you're just working from an existing codebase of course, but maybe you're also designing the datamodel and/or have the power to change it?

Comment: You're right but I am working from an existing codebase, do you know if it can be done without changing the model to have a separate versions table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it is possible. Note that a select list expects you to return the data in rows, so we will need to convert the concatenated string to rows.
Personally I like using XML to do this:

```
SELECT trim(val)
FROM 
  xmltable('/root/e/text()' passing XMLTYPE('<root><e>'
  || REPLACE('1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4',',','</e><e>')
  || '</e></root>') columns val VARCHAR2(50) path '/' )
```

Will return

```
TRIM(VAL)
---------
1.1
1.2
1.3
1.4
```

So you could apply it like this:

```
WITH prd_versions AS (
  SELECT versions FROM products WHERE id = :PX_PRODUCT_ID
)
SELECT trim(val)
FROM prd_versions p,
  xmltable('/root/e/text()' passing XMLTYPE('<root><e>'
  || REPLACE(p.v,',','</e><e>')
  || '</e></root>') columns val VARCHAR2(50) path '/' )
```

There are of course other ways to split a string into rows, as a quick Google can show you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a simple form, not a tabular form, then you can do this:

1. Create a hidden item to hold the value of column product.versions e.g. P1_VERSIONS.
2. Set the "List of Value Definition" for the select list to: `STATIC2:&P1_VERSIONS.`

(You may need to trim spaces from the value stored in P1_VERSIONS.)